# PoolParty Login using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have Python 3.4 installed on my system. How do I login to the website http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login using a python script?

Code 1:

```
import requests

login_page = "http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login"
sess = requests.session()
sess.post(login_page, {"j_username": "User", "j_password": "Pass"})
```

Code 2:

```
import requests, json

login_url='http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login'

r = requests.post(login_url, auth=('myuser','mypass'))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Both the codes return error 400 and urllib2 does not work on my system. 
Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you're posting to the wrong url? The web page contains a form which posts to a different url to login.

Have you tried this:

```
import requests

login_page = "http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/j_spring_security_check"
sess = requests.session()
resp = sess.post(login_page, {"j_username": "User", "j_password": "Pass"})
print resp.status_code
print resp.content
```

I think it might do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're simply sending a POST request to the login page, not actually performing the login. I've checked the website you're referring, and the URL you need to use to login is:

```
http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/j_spring_security_check
```

... and the `POST` data it's expecting is:

```
j_username=test&j_password=test
```

Simply make a `POST` Request to this URL like so:

```
login_url = 'http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/j_spring_security_check'

# Perform the login
r = requests.post(login_url, data={
    'j_username': 'someusername',
    'j_password': 'somepassword'
})
```

Upon request, the site in question will respond with a `location` header included in it's response. This will redirect you back to the login page if unsuccessful. You can use this in your code to check if the login was successful or not.

Invalid login requests are redirected to:

```
http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login
```

In code you can check this easily:

```
if r.headers['location'] == 'http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login':
    print 'Login Failed'
```

By default Requests will automatically follow the `location` header.

Answer (score -1):

Use requests.get not post, it works for me

```
import requests, json

login_url='http://termmanagement.poolparty.biz/PoolParty/!/auth/login'

r = requests.get(login_url, auth=('myuser','mypass'))
```

Comment: Get works; but I need to log in and go to another page. Will get do that?